# Avoid using instanceof when dealing with instances of java.lang.Object

Tags: java, object, instanceof

I do have a few instanceof checks in ym code, but there are some I wish I could avoid. Usually whenever there is more than one if statement, for example:

```
public void setValue(Object newValue) {
    //dateTime is a member variable of the type java.util.Date
    if (newValue instanceof Date) {
      dateTime = new DateTime((Date) newValue);

    } else if (newValue instanceof Calendar) {
      dateTime = MyDateTimeUtils.toDate((Calendar)newValue);

    } else if (newValue instanceof String) {
      dateTime = MyDateTimeUtils.toDate((String)newValue);
    }
}
```

MyDateTimeUtils is simply a utility class that converts date/time types (Calendar to Date, Date to Calendar, String to Date etc...).

My main issue is, that newValue is of the instance Object (I can't change the method signature, as it's part of a framework that handles databinding). If it was something tangible I guess it would be simpler and I could have that class implement an interface that offers a conversion method to Date. But since it's of the type Object I am not sure how to get around those instanceof checks?

Comment: I don't think there is anything you can (or need to) do about this.

Comment: @Thilo the way it currently is, I really seem to be unable to change something, so I guess I'll have to tear down and rebuild the foundation that's causing those instanceof calls in the first place :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your major constraint is:

> **I can't change the method signature**

With this constraint, I think there is no way to get around the `instanceof` usage. All you ever have in your method is an `Object`.

If you could at least add additional overloads for `setValue(Object newValue)`, you could add the necessary ones for `Date`, `Calendar` and `String`:

```
public void setValue(Date newValue) {}
public void setValue(Calendar newValue) {}
public void setValue(String newValue) {}
```

The compiler would then choose **at compile time** the proper method through its signature. 
Java does not support [multiple dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch) (deciding which method to call based on the parameter types **at runtime**),
so it is not possible to let the `setValue(Object newValue)` automatically dispatch back to the matching overload.

Comment: +1 I really like your suggestion, but I am afraid it won't do, as I'd require multiple dispatch for that approach. However I'll mark this as the correct answer, since under normal circumstances I'd do it this way. However it got me thinking, that maybe I should modify my framework to pass a concrete type (like string for instance) rather than Objects. This way I'll always know what to expect and I could lose the instanceof statements.